# Detect sound from video with Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, audio

I want to know, is it possible to add something like addEventListener or something else, for listen to sound output with Javascript. Is is possible to detect speech volume in video? I mean, I want to use for example `alert("Speech!");` function when sound begins to come from video. Thanks!

Comment: you want to detect when audio stream begins on a video you are playing on the page, via JavaScript?

Comment: I am not expert in audio/video, but I have a feeling this might not be possible with just JavaScript. You might require some sort of server side processing. i.e. When a video is uploaded to your site, your upload handler processes the video and records when the audio stream starts and gives you cues. Then when you play the video, you also supply the audio cues to the javascript. When the video plays, you start a timer and everytime your timer ticks towards the cues, you can alert. just an idea...

Comment: Thanks, for the idea, is there any example about it, or not?

Comment: Sorry no exampls that i can think of. However, a good start would be `ffmpeg` extension for PHP. More info here http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg-php/ and this https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Using%20FFmpeg%20from%20PHP%20scripts and http://www.emoticode.net/php/ffmpeg-example-script.html